# Javascript xhr post body containing two objects as one

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to send two objects to a web api (ASP.NET) , User and House.

Initially, I tried to send them as xhr.send(User,House), but I realized you can only send one object per body.

So, I created a wrapper class to contain both of the objects

```
    public class Wrapper
{
    public House house{ get; set; }
    public User user{ get; set; }

}
```

However, when I send the json body into the api, the data receives the data object as null.

What am I doing wrong?

Front End :

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var url = "api_call";
 xhr.open('POST', url); 
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

 var house = JSON.stringify({address : address, zip : zip});
 var user =  JSON.stringify({Email: email, Password: "aaaAAA1!"});
 var wrapper = JSON.stringify({house : house, user : user});
 ... 
 xhr.send(wrapper);
```

Back End:

```
        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> ApiCall(Wrapper wrapper)
    {
    // wrapper.house and wrapper.user is null
        House house = wrapper.house;
        User user= wrapper.user;
   ...
   }
```

Comment: There is no need to stringify `house` and `user`, just stingify `wrapper` is enough , so initiate house and user to wrapper as object not string

Comment: Try to change the web-api signature to `public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> ApiCall([FromBody] Wrapper wrapper)`

Comment: And decorate the `ApiCall` by `[HttpPost]`

Comment: @Aria Not stringifying house and user did it. Please add an answer so that you may receive credit.

Comment: @Mocha, Good to hear that, so it is resolved ?

Comment: @Aria Yes, it is resolved. thanks

Comment: @Mocha, You are welcome .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As our conversation as comment, 
There is no need to `stringify` house and user, just `stringify` wrapper is enough , so initiate house and user to wrapper as object not string, the correction would be something like :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var url = "api_call";
 xhr.open('POST', url); 
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

 var wrapper = JSON.stringify({house : {address : address, zip : zip}, user : {Email: email, Password: "aaaAAA1!"}});
 ... 
 xhr.send(wrapper);
```